# Custom Label text in tableview when data found or not? objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I tried to find a solution but so far no luck, i can show a custom label in a tableview where the `numberOfSections` is returned zero if there is not data in an array else i am returning what is required.

Now I am sending a Json request in a `viewDidLoad` so I can populate data in a tableview. when the view loaded, initially I am getting No data found in a custom label which is fine as the initial array is empty and changing the text to "fetching data please wait" when I am sending a JSO request but that does not have any effect and I am constantly shown no data found.

Can you guys please advise what am I missing?

Please don't post a solution with `numberOfRows` as `1` and section returned as `1`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: llyas have you checked array count before populating table? Are you reloading table on main thread? There are many things you can check and solve , use breakpoint to debug.

Comment: Can you upload some code for more clarity

Comment: Tushar, yes i have checked what you wrote above and everything is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After getting Json Array Check this Condition.

```
if( [YourJsonArray count]==0)
{
  [self showalert:@"" msg:@"No data found"];    
 }
else
{
  [self.tbleView reloadData];
}
```

Alert Method

```
-(void)showalert:(NSString *)strTitle  msg :(NSString *)message
{ 
 UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:strTitle
                                                              message:message
                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

 UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok "
                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                            {

                            }];

[alert addAction:yesButton];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And you can use YourJsonArray in tableview in numberofrows or Section according your requirement

Comment: lalit, i dont want to hide a lable, i just wanna change the text of that label when the request is sent to "fetching data please wait" and if no record found, i wanna change text to "NO data found". by your solution i am hiding and unhiding the lable which is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Following code for your reference.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSInteger numOfSections = 0;
    if ([searchArray count] )
    {
        self.tableView = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        numOfSections                = 1;
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
    else{

    if ([results count])
    {
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        numOfSections = 1;
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        self.noDataLabel.text             = @"No Data Available";
        self.noDataLabel.textColor        = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.noDataLabel.textAlignment    = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.tableView.backgroundView = self.noDataLabel;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }
    }
    return numOfSections;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSUInteger rows =0;
    if(self.searchBar.text.length > 0){
        rows = [searchArray count];
        return rows;
    }
    else{

     rows = results.count;

    }
    DLog(@"%ld",rows);
    return rows;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];

    if((self.searchBar.text.length > 0)){

        sObject * searchObj = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] ;
        [cell setData:searchObj];
    }
    else if([results count] == 0){
        return cell;
    }
    else {

    sObject * ordObj = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setData:ordObj];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

and i am adding the following line before sending `Json` request

```
self.noDataLabel.text = @".. Fetching Data Please Wait ..";
```